# Replace file path in VBA with user name

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with VBA written on it that draws information from a file on my computer. The Excel file is on a network folder and I would like for other users on the network to use it as well. However, I have hardcoded the file path on the VBA and, as such, whenever another user opens it, it looks for a file that is not available.

This is the path I would like to change:

```
C:\Users\User1\Documents\The Market in\DATA FOR REPORTS.xlsx
```

The only difference on the paths would be the user's name: User1, user2, etc.

How can I write the VBA code in order for it to replace the username in the file path with the Windows user name opening it?

I have tried to use wild card and also tried to use ENVIRON("username") but have not been successful.

The code I want to replace is what's below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Visible = False
WelcomeForm.Show
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\User1\Documents\The Market in\DATA FOR REPORTS.xlsx")

End Sub
```

This is what I did using ENVIRON:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim username As String

username = Environ("username")

Application.Visible = False
WelcomeForm.Show
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\&username&\Documents\The Market in\DATA FOR REPORTS.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: `Environ("Username")` should work. Can you show how did you use it and what was the problem/error?

Comment: I've just added it to the question. Thank you or your help!

Comment: This is not correct concatenation syntax - `"C:\Users\&username&\Documents` - look carefully at the answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Visible = False
   WelcomeForm.Show
   Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\The Market in\DATA FOR REPORTS.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Environ("userprofile")` will return the path & username.
On my PC it returns `C:\Users\darren.bartrup-cook`

Another way is:
`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")`
On my PC this returns `C:\Users\darren.bartrup-cook\Documents`

You could use it like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wrkBK As Workbook
    Dim DocFldr As String

    DocFldr = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

    Set wrkBK = Workbooks.Open(DocFldr & "\The Market in\DATA FOR REPORTS.xlsx")

    MsgBox wrkBK.Name & " is open", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```